# Calypso Compliance module - Menu bar doesn't appear

Tags: calypso

After installing the compliance module in my local Calypso, no menu bar appears when loging into the module.
I have started dataserver, analysisserver, riskserver and ERS Compliance server.
Find attached a screenshot of the empty module bar.
[image: screenshot of empty module bar]

Am I missing something in the installation? I have followed the steps on the documentation and I can't find what else should I have to do to see the menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution to the problem.

It was an access permissions related issue. Even though I had configured ALL in the functions of my user, I had to add the compliance related permissions as well. As you can see in the screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWw1o.png)

After adding those functions, I started again the compliance module and now the menu bar appears with all the options:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uCm9.png)

I hope someone finds this information usefull!